basic math question of algebra and exponents
I was reading the Schaum book of finantial math and i find this question:
$$15000(1-d)^{11} = 800$$
$$(1-d)^{11} = 800/15000$$
$$ 1-d = (800/15000)^{1/11}$$
$$ d = 1- (800/15000)^{1/11}$$
and the book proposes a solution to it that is:
$$d = 0.233922668$$
the problem is that i think the author has made a mistake in the negative sign, because when you move the 1 on the left it will leave the -d and the 1 will go to the right as negative.
when i try to solve it, i came up with the question that this part
$$ d = 1- (800/15000)^{1/11}$$
should be
$$ d = (800/15000)^{1/11} -1 $$
I know it is a simple question, but i have no one to ask, so i hope you can help me. Thanks !!
I don't know if my way of thinking is the correct or the book.

I get the same result as the book.

$1-d$ is not negative. You should solve $15000x^{11}=800$. No need to write $x=1-d$ before solving the other equation.

$1-d$ can't be negative, as @DietrichBurde said. You see, you're multiplying 15000, which is positive, to (1-d) raised to an  "odd" power, and getting 800, which is also positive. So $1-d$ must be positive.

$$1-d=N\implies d=1-N$$
is correct and not what you propose:
$$1-d=N\implies d=N-1$$
Here, go step by step
$$\begin{aligned}
1-d&=N\\
1-d+d&=N+d\\
1&=N+d\\
1-N&=N+d-N\\
1-N&=d
\end{aligned}$$
Hope this helps. :)

There is no mistake in the authors derivation.
As for the sign issue you have, there are 2 ways to see that the author's derivation is correct as follows:
Starting from:
$$ 1-d = (800/15000)^{1/11}$$
Let $n=(800/15000)^{1/11}$
You have:
$$1-d=n$$
Short road:
Move (-d) to right hand side and flip its sign to get:
$$1=n+d$$
Move (n) to left hand side and flip its sign to get:
$$1-n=d$$
Long road:
given: $$ 1-d = n$$
Add $(-n)$ to both sides:
$$1-n-d=0$$
Add $d$ to both sides:
$$1-n-d+(d)=d$$
Finally,
$$1-n=d$$
